# How to improve animation performance on Android?

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, objectanimator

I am animating an image view by changing its height with ValueAnimator.
Problem is that it sometimes lags a bit (doesn't begin smoothly) even though about 80% of the times it does go quite smoothly.

The image view has four other Views constrained to it, so I am also animating them to fade out with ObjectAnimator as the image view is collapsing.

I am using 2 AnimatorSet-s to synchronize them.

I tried using TransitionManager in a different ways as well as tried playing around with the Property animators. The result was the same.

Tried also setting the layer types of the views to LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE and LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE. Same result.

I was also thinking the use of two AnimatorSet-s might have been something that slows the animation, but I tried removing the fading animations and the collapse was still laggy sometimes.

I think the problem lies in the layout and its complexity.

It's a ConstraintLayout in a NestedScrollView.
Inside, the ConstraintLayout has:

1) a nested ConstraintLayout;

2) two RecyclerView-s;

3) an `included` LinearLayout with 4 repeatedly fading in and out Views that is View.GONE by the time the animation starts;

4) a CardView with a nested LienarLayout which CardView is also View.GONE;

5) 1 Button, 1 View, 5 TextView-s;

6) My addition to the layout -> the collapsing background ImageView, another small ImageView, 2 x TextView, TextInputLayout + TextInputEditText, and a Button.

When I tried removing stuff the animation gets better, and is 100% smooth when I remove the nested ConstraintLayout and the RecyclerView-s.

In reality though, the only thing I can think of doing is to remove the nested ConstrainLayout and constraining the views inside it to appear the same way they did before.

Does anyone have ideas on how to improve performance here?
Bear in mind that I'm quite limited in my actions since this is not a personal app.

Thank you very much!

Providing my code below:

```
AnimatorSet().apply {
    playTogether {
        getCollapseAnimation(),
        getFadingViewsAnimatorSet()
    }
    start()
}

fun getCollapseAnimation(): ValueAnimator {
    return ValueAnimator.ofInt(imageView.measuredHeight, 0).apply {
        addUpdateListener {
            val params = imageView.layoutParams
            params.height = it.animatedValue as Int
            imageView.layoutParams = params
        }
        duration = 500
    }
}

fun getFadingViewsAnimatorSet(): AnimatorSet {
    val fadeAmim1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view1, View.ALPHA, 0f)
    val fadeAnim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view2, View.ALPHA, 0f)
    val fadeAnim3 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view3, View.ALPHA, 0f)
    val fadeAnim4 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view4, View.ALPHA, 0f)
    return AnimatorSet().apply {
        playTogether(fadeAnim1, fadeAnim2, fadeAnim3, fadeAnim4)
        duration = 200
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your xml layout

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure if it's OK to post someone else's code here. I would have posted it otherwise.

Comment: I am pretty sure it has to do with your layout's complexity. You can also merge the two RecyclerView into one. A small thing I would suggest is making `getFadingViewsAnimatorSet()` to return a list of `ObjectAnimator` and set the duration on each individual fade animation. The global `AnimatorSet` can take a collection for the `#playTogether()`.

Comment: Nice, thanks, I'll try that. Btw, I tried removing the nested ConstraintLayout and adjusting the views that were inside to the new conditions and it seems to have gotten worse. Thought it should have been an improvement... :D